# AZURE API : AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

I am trying to call a Azure Token retrieval API endpoint from a SAP Fiori application via a BTP destination. Getting below error while executing the token retrieval call.

[image]

Below is my destination:

[image]

Alternatively when I try to call the actual API endpoint with OAuth2UserTokenExchange I am getting HTTP 500 Internal Server error without any error description.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to reproduce the same in my environment in **Postman** and got the **same error** as below:*

[image]

The error "***AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type***" usually occurs if you are using PKCE flow/SPA authentication and the Azure AD Application is configured as web like below:

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make sure to configure the Azure AD Application as SPA like below:

[image]

After the above changes, **I am able to get the access token successfully** like below:

Make sure to add **`origin`** in the Headers:

[image]

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

In your case, add the redirect URI **`https://port8080-workspace*****`** as SPA in Authentication blade of the Azure AD Application.

Comment: This solved my issue, changing web to spa