# msal-node - Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented in nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

When i am trying to genrate new access token from refresh token this error occurs"Token acquisition error: ServerError: invalid_client: 700025 - [2023-06-15 04:02:04Z]: AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented."

```
if(createEventResponse === undefined){
                    console.log("token-expired")

                    // const accessToken = await  req.app.locals.msalClient.refreshToken(refreshToken);
                    // console.log(accessToken)
                    const scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"];

                    const pca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

                    pca.acquireTokenByRefreshToken({
                      refreshToken: refreshToken,
                      scopes: scopes,

                    })
                      .then((response:any) => {
                        // New access token acquisition successful
                        console.log(response)
                        const newAccessToken = response.accessToken;
                        console.log('New Access token:', newAccessToken);

                        // Use the new access token for further operations
                        // ...
                      })
                      .catch((error) => {
                        // Token acquisition failed
                        console.error('Token acquisition error:', error);
                      });

 /*                    const accessToken = await msalClient.acquireTokenSilent(scopes, refreshToken);
                    console.log("new access token");
                    console.log(accessToken);

                    const retryCreateEventResponse = await createOutlookEventService(accessToken, formData, "Pacific Standard Time");
                    console.log(retryCreateEventResponse) */
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to generate **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
```

I got the **same error** like below:

[image]

The error "***AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented***"  usually occurs if the Azure AD Application is configured as Public Client and you are trying to pass Client Secret while generating the tokens.

Check whether the **Application is Public Client or not** like below:

[image]

**To resolve the error,** Check the below:

- If you want your **application to be as Public Client** then do not pass Client Secret while generating the tokens in your code.
- ***If not***, then configure the application as Web/SPA and set `Enable the following mobile and desktop flows` as No, then pass the Client Secret to generate the tokens.

Without passing Client Secret for an **Azure AD Public Client Application**, I am able to generate the access and refresh token successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: getting this error 
AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.
i have refresh token from ui and i am storing in database so when access token is expire then from backend 
ConfidentialClientApplication and  pca.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(tokenRequest)
i am trying to genrate new token from refresh token

Comment: getting this error 
AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.
i have refresh token from ui and i am storing in database so when access token is expire then from backend 
ConfidentialClientApplication and  pca.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(tokenRequest)
i am trying to genrate new token from refresh token

Comment: If you are configuring app SPA then make use of PKCE flow.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438571/azure-api-aadsts9002326-cross-origin-token-redemption-is-permitted-only-for-t#76438874